# Как интегрировать код php, в интегрированный код html, в интегрированный код php?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php 


?>


<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

        <div class="container mt-5">
                
                <form action="check.php" method="post">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Имя исполнителя</label>
                    <input type="text" name="authorName" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Название трека</label>
                    <input type="text" name="trackName" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
                  <button type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-primary float-right mt-1">Submit</button>
                </form>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <?php 
            $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'kinofilmi');
            $query = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM music');

            while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
                echo $row['trackName'],  '<div class="">
        
        <div class="">
          <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">

            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text"> <?php echo $row["TrackName"]; ?></p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Слушать</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Добавить</button>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>        

      </div>';
            }

            $id = $row['id'];
            $name = $row['trackName'];
            $author = $row['authorName'];



         ?>

    </div>

        </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Вот код, там где card-text я попробовал заставить выводить название трека из базы данных, но у меня не вышло. Подскажите, что можно с этим сделать.)

Comment: может слегка подотделить html от sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<p class="card-text">'.$row["TrackName"].'</p>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!